# Command line to go in directory passed by which command

Tags: linux, command-line, cd-command

I want use a command such as this :

```
 which node && cd $_
```

to jump in the directory when the binary file reside, but the which command return all the path + name of binary ,so i get an error :

```
 bash: cd: node: No such file or directory
```

I'm looking for new command move me in the right place.

Answer (score 3):

[Don't use which](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/85249/38906) (unless you're in `csh` or `tcsh` variants), it's broken. Using [command -v node](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/command.html) instead.

POSIX offer [dirname](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/dirname.html) command to get the directory portion of pathname:

```
cd "$(dirname -- "$(command -v node)")"
```

or using a variable to store the pathname, prevent you from calling `dirname`:

```
nodepath=$(command -v node)
cd "${nodepath%/*}"
```

Answer (score 1):

Meanwhile, in ZShell, this requires the quite ugly and awkward construct:

```
cd -- $commands[node]:h
```

This even works when there's directories with spaces in their name (unless for unfathomable reasons you enabled the `shwordsplit` option).

Comment: Shorter: `cd =node(:h)` (you only need the `--` here if you have a relative directory starting with `-` or `+` in your PATH).

Answer (score -1):

```
cd $(dirname $(which bash))
```

Good luck :)